# Looping through an array of objects and display them in HTML

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, loops

Im a beginner at coding and I want to solve the following task:

I created 3 different classes. The main class is the **Place class**, followed by a **restaurant class** and **events class**. Both the **restaurant class** and **events class** inherit the basic properties from the **Place class** and have extra properties specific only to themselves.
Each class have a **display() function**, displaying their specific content. I created 2 objects per class. All objects created are placed in an array, that should be looped through to display each object on my page.

Class with the display function:

```
class Place {
Name = "";
City = "";
ZIP = "";
Address = "";
Image = "";

constructor(Name, City, ZIP, Address, Image){
    this.Name = Name;
    this.City = City;
    this.ZIP = ZIP;
    this.Address = Address;
    this.Image = Image;
}

display(){
    $("cardContainer").append(`
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img src="${this.Image}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">${this.Name}</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">${this.City},<br>${this.ZIP} ${this.Address}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
        `);
}
```

I have the **restaurant** and the **events classes** the same manner. Then I created **an array** and pushed the objects:

```
let placesArr = [];

placesArr.push(
    new Place(
        "La Sagrada Familia",
        "Barcelona",
        "08013",
        "Carrer de Mallorca 401.",
        "img/sagradafamilia.jpg"
        )
);
new restaurant(
    "Raco del Nuria",
    "Barcelona",
    "08002",
    "La Rambla 133.",
    "img/racodelnuria.jpg",
    "+34-933-01-05-77",
    "Mediterranean",
    "racodelnuria.com"
);
new events(
    "FC Barcelona vs. Athletic Club de Bilbao",
    "Barcelona",
    "08028",
    "C. d'Aristides Maillol 12.",
    "img/foci.jpg",
    "06.23.2020",
    "22:00",
    "from 29 euro"
);
```

I tried the console.table and all the code above works because I have all the data in the console.

At the end I only need to looping through the array and display in the HTML, which only has an empty div with the **class="row"** and **id="cardContainer"**, but I dont know how. Can anybody help me?

Comment: If the `id` of the element you're looking to append to is called "cardContainer", then your selector should be prefixed with `#`. For example, `$("#cardContainer").append(...)`

Comment: You've hard-coded your `display()` function to append the HTML of the `Place` to a `cardContainer` element, like `<cardContainer>` if you want it to go to a `<div id="cardContainer" class="row">`, you should use `$('#cardContainer').append(...);`.  Once you fix that, it's just a matter of calling `.display()` on each element in your array.

Comment: I managed to display the content in the HTML, but I guess its not a nice solution:

let doIt = placesArr;
for(let i = 0; i < doIt.lenght; i++) {
 display(doIt[i]);
}

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have the display function to append template literal html, try using the following code

```
placesArr.forEach(place => place.display())
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of following example:

```
var table = '<md-table-container>' +
            '<table class="md-table" border="1" style="text-align:center">' +
            '<thead class="md-head">' +
             '<tr md-row>';
              for (i = 0;i < data.length; i++) { //here you can use your array
                 table += '<th class="md-column">' + data[i] + '</th>';
              }
              table += '</tr></thead>';
              table += '</table></md-table-container>';
```

Then you can use 
     `$("cardContainer").append(table)`